# How do I install Drupal with a custom language?

Tags: 8, drush, i18n-l10n, installation

I know I can install a new Drupal web site with:

```
drush dl drupal --drupal-project-rename=[project]
cd [project]
drush site-install standard \
    --db-url='mysql://[db_user]:[db_pass]@localhost/[db_name]' \
    --site-name=Example
```

But how can I install Drupal 8 with some custom language, let's say italian, using Drush?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems this works fine:

```
$ drush si standard \
    --db-url='mysql://[db_user]:[db_pass]@localhost/[db_name]' \
    --account-name=joe --account-pass=mom \
    --site-name=Example \
    --site-mail=noreply@example.com \
    --locale=it
```